# How to find min of two variables in linux

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

i have two variables 
$a and $b

is there shell script command to assign the value of minimum variable to $c

i.e

```
$c = min($a,$b)
```

and some command that can work across all platforms hp-ux,aix,linux_x_64

thanks in advance

EDIT:
default shell is ksh

and below the script im trying to run

```
rm abc.log 
near_dr=`sqlplus -s tcs384160/tcs#1234 <<\EOF
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off
select max(sequence#) from v$archived_log where applied='YES' and thread#=1 and 
dest_id=2;


exit;
EOF`
DR=`sqlplus -s tcs384160/tcs#1234 <<\EOF
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off 

select max(sequence#) from v$archived_log where applied='YES' and thread#=1 and

 dest_id=3;
 exit;
 EOF`
safe_var=$([ $near_dr -le $DR ] && echo "$near_dr" || echo "$DR")
echo $safe_var;
ulimit=`expr $safe_var - 30`;
llimit=`expr $ulimit - 1000`;
echo $llimit;
echo $ulimit;
i=$llimit
while [ $i -le $ulimit ];
do
  ls  evdprd_1_${i}_*.arc>>abc.log;
  let i=i+1;
done;




recover -s ttlhydnwr -c tphtpsd2<<EOF  >> abc.log
ls -1 *.arc
exit
EOF
sed -e 's/[\t ]//g;/^$/d' abc.log > abc1.log
awk '++seen[$0] == 2' abc1.log > actual.log
```

please ignore the sqlplus parts as those are working fine the only problem is the $safe_var needing the minimum of the two values

Answer (score 8):

There is no function, but you can create it:

```
(( $a <= $b )) && echo "$a" || echo "$b"
```

The `condition && action1 || action2` does evaluate the condition. If it is true, then perform `action1`; otherwise, perform `action2`.

To store the result into a variable, do:

```
min=$( (( $a <= $b )) && echo "$a" || echo "$b" )
```

---

### Update

It seems that the `$( (( )) )` syntax is giving problems. Hence, let's replace it to:

```
[ $a -le $b ] && echo "$a" || echo "$b"
```

or assigning value:

```
min=$([ $a -le $b ] && echo "$a" || echo "$b")
```

#### Sample

```
$ a=3
$ b=4
$ [ $a -le $b ] && echo "$a" || echo "$b"
3

$ b=1
$ [ $a -le $b ] && echo "$a" || echo "$b"
1

$ b=3
$ [ $a -le $b ] && echo "$a" || echo "$b"
3
```

Comment: What's your shell? Are you working on shell, zsh, ksh, bash? Give more info if you want to get more help.

Comment: Uhms, @user3186568 I just updated with another approach.

Comment: sorry dint mean to im new to this website can i undo it

Comment: Well you have a time to unvote, it is about 5 min. Then the vote gets frozen unless the post is edited. But don't worry if it is a mistake, I just don't like downvotes without explanation :)

Comment: Have you deployed the code? What's the value of `$near_dr` and `$DR`? Are you sure they are just numbers?

Answer (score 4):

You could do in this way too:

```
x=1
y=2
echo $(($x<$y?$x:$y))
1
```

To store value in other variable:

```
z=$(($x<$y?$x:$y))   #Min
z=$(($x<=$y?$x:$y))  #Min and equal
z=$(($x>$y?$x:$y))   #Greater
z=$(($x>=$y?$x:$y))  #Greater and equal
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention less than or equal to,thanks though

Comment: syntax error at line 13: `min=$' unexpected getting this error while i tried your logic can u suggest a workaround

Comment: I don't get that error. I execute x=1 and y=2 to get values in the variables. When you execute "z=$(($x<=$y?$x:$y))" you get the value 1 in z. The code is like a lambda: ((CONDITION?RESULT1:RESULT2)) IF CONDITION IS TRUE, THEN RESULT1 IF NOT RESULT2

Comment: does it have anything to do with the shell

Comment: syntax error at line 12: `safe_var=$' unexpected (please see the edit on my question

Answer (score 1):

In ksh, this works fine

```
$ near_dr=5 DR=10                        
$ save_var=$(( near_dr < DR ? near_dr : DR )) ; echo $save_var
5
$ near_dr=15 DR=10                                            
$ save_var=$(( near_dr < DR ? near_dr : DR )) ; echo $save_var
10
$ near_dr=15 DR=15                                            
$ save_var=$(( near_dr < DR ? near_dr : DR )) ; echo $save_var
15
```

So you can write a function:

```
min() {
    echo $(( $1 < $2 ? $1 : $2 ))
}

safe_var=$(min $near_dr $DR)
```

This is the same as @Liaraz's answer, except "Variables can be referenced by name within an arithmetic
       expression without using the parameter expansion syntax." (ksh man page, section Arithmetic evaluation)

Comment: ksh93 apparently lets you define arithmetic functions so you can do `safe_var=$(( min(near_dr, DR) ))`, but I haven't figured out how to return the value. `function .sh.math.min a b { echo $(( a<=b ? a : b )); }` prints the correct value, but returns `nan`

Comment: getting the syntax error at line 17: `safe_var=$' unexpected
error

Comment: what is your ksh version?

Comment: You assign the numeric return value by assigning to `.sh.value` - source: [ast-users, 2012](http://lists.research.att.com/pipermail/ast-users/2012q1/003026.html)

Comment: Added a full answer for the custom arithmetic function based on that reference.

Answer (score 1):

Ksh93 custom arithmetic function example:

```
function .sh.math.min a b {
.sh.value=$(( a<b ? a : b ))
}
$ echo $(( min(1,3) ))                                        
1
$ echo $(( min(5,3) ))
3
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure the value of variables are integers, use @fedorqui's answer. It's short and neat.

however, if you are not sure about that, they could be e.g. float numbers:

```
kent$ a=3.57
kent$ b=13.5
kent$ (($a < $b)) && echo "y" || echo "n"
bash: ((: 3.57 < 13.5: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".57 < 13.5")
n
```

this would work for all cases:

```
kent$ awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" 'BEGIN{print (a>b)?b:a}'
3.57
```